# $E(x) = \mathbb{I}_{n} - xx^{*} $ is nonsingular if and only if $x^{*}x \neq 1$

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

We define the matrix $E(x) := \mathbb{I}_{n} - xx^{*}  $ , where $ \mathbb{I}_{n} $ is the identity matrix of $n \times n$  and $x \in \mathbb{C}^{n}$ ($x$ is a column matrix) and $x^{*}$ is the conjugate transpose of $x$. Here's my attempt

$(\leftarrow )$
suppose that $x^{*}x \neq 1$ and also that $E(x)$ is singular, that is, $\det(E(x)) = 0$. Since the $\det(E(x))$ is the product of the eigenvalues of $E(x)$ , then we have that $\lambda_{1} = 0$ is an eigenvalue of $E(x)$ associated  to an nonzero eigenvector $v$. This means that:

$$ E(x)v = \lambda_{1}v = 0 $$ then $$ (\mathbb{I}_{n}-xx^{*})v = v -x x^{*}v = 0$$ this implies that

$$ xx^{*}v = v $$ which means that $xx^{*}$ has eigenvalue $\lambda=1$.
I'm stuck and I don't know how to start the other direction. 
How would you do it? ...thank you!!

Comment: cf. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2920189/the-matrix-i-n-vt-x-is-invertible-when-langle-v-x-rangle-neq-1/2920305#2920305

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $I-xx^*$ is singular, then as you say $xx^*$ has $1$ as an eigenvalue; it follows that   $x^*x=1$. Indeed,  if $xx^*v=v$, then $x^*x(x^*v)=x^*v$; and $x^*v\ne0$ since $x^*v=0$ implies $v=xx^*v=0$.

Conversely, if $x^*x=1$, then $xx^*x=x$, so $(I-xx^*)x=0$ and thus $I-xx^*$ is singular.

Comment: how do you know that $xv$ is well-defined?

Comment: You are right; $v$ was not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Your question recalls the equivalence of a square matrix $M$ being singular and $\,\det M =0\,$.

When relying on [Sylvester's determinant identity](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2013/01/13/matrix-identities-as-derivatives-of-determinant-identities/)
$$\det\big(\mathbb{I}_n + AB\big)\; =\;\det\big(\mathbb I_m + BA\big)\qquad\forall\: A\in M_{n\times m}\,\text{ and }\,B\in M_{m\times n}$$
then with $x\in\mathbb C^n = M_{n\times 1}(\mathbb C)\,$ you obtain 
$$\begin{align}
\det\big(\mathbb{I}_n-xx^*\big)\; & =\;\det\big(\mathbb I_1-x^*x\big) \\[1ex]
 & =\;1-x^*x\;=\; 1-\|x\|^2
\end{align}$$ 
which gives the claim: $\,\mathbb{I}_n-xx^*\,$ is singular iff $x$ is a unit vector (in the 2-norm).